# Como reverter um commit específico da master?

Tags: git, commit

Estou precisando reverter um commit específico que está remoto. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro verifique se o git push --force está ativo no seu repositório.

**Descubra o hash do commit seguindo estes passos:**

***Acesse o Repositório***

[image: Acesse o Repositório]

***Pegue o Commit***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Copie o HASH e substitua no comando abaixo***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Depois, execute os seguintes comandos:***

```
git reset --hard HASH_DO_COMMIT_QUE_QUER_VOLTAR

git push --force
```

O git reset voltará a sua branch pro hash que você passou.

O git push --force forçará o push desse hash, sobrescrevendo o atual no git.

Comment: Obrigado, eu estava fazendo só o reset e quando dava sync voltava tudo as alterações passadas.